how to plot high and loe of 3rd candle on an hourly chart
I need the high and low of the 3 hour candle on an hourly chart starting from the week.
//@version=5
indicator("test", overlay = true)
NEWWK = timeframe.change("W")
bgcolor(NEWWK ? #7f7f7caa: na)

barsSinceBeginingOfWeek = ta.barssince(NEWWK)
var plotLine = false
barnumber = ta.barssince(NEWWK)
if barsSinceBeginingOfWeek == 3
    plotline := true

h = ta.valuewhen(plotline, high, 0)
plot(h, "high", color.red,1)
plot(barsSinceBeginingOfWeek, "Bn", color.white, 2)


this is what I am trying to do, can anybody help me? Thanks

i know the code is messed, but it is what I was trying
